# Is there a generalized setter for buffer-modified-p?

Tags: let-binding, setf

It is very simple to define a simple generalized setter for `buffer-modified-p`:

```el
(gv-define-simple-setter buffer-modified-p set-buffer-modified-p)
```

That enables constructs like:

```el
(with-current-buffer "test.cc"
  (cl-letf (((buffer-modified-p) t))
    (save-buffer)))
```

If `test.cc` is out-of-sync it is saved even if `(buffer-modified-p)` returns nil. The old status of `(buffer-modified-p)` is unconditionally restored afterwards.

I use that in a special case where there is a special save function which unsets `buffer-modified-p` but does not save the buffer in the file associated with `buffer-file-name`.

**Question:** Is that generalized setter already defined in some existing library?

Note, I know about `with-buffer-modified-unmodified` from `bookmarks.el`. But, that is not quite what I want.

Comment: +1. Seems like maybe there should be a simple way to ask this of Emacs. At least for predefined setters, maybe `C-h v` help could/should mention the known setter(s). If you think so, maybe file an enhancement request (?).